# How do I pivot this data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a query that spits out the following data:

```
 ID      | RESPONSE_VALUE                       | TITLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1634303 | 6th Grade - Referring teacher's room | Academic_Area
 1634303 | doing stuff and thangs               | Help
 1634303 | Doe, Jane                            | Name
 1634303 | Doe, John                            | Name_of_Student
 1634303 | 1 Day                                | Days
 1634303 | Tuesday                              | Preferred_PAWs_Day
 1634303 | Online                               | materials
```

I want to pivot this data so it looks like this:

```
   ID    | Academic_Area                          | Help                     | Name        | Name_of_Student | Days    | Preferred_PAWs_Day | materials
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1634303 | "6th Grade - Referring teacher's room" | "doing stuff and thangs" | "Doe, Jane" | "John,  Doe"    | "1 Day" | Tuesday            | ""
```

Since this kind of data doesn't really have an aggregate function that makes sense to feed into, I'm not seeing a good way to pivot the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` or just `max()` (if only one value is involved).

For instance:

```
select id,
       max(case when response_value = '6th Grade - Referring teacher''s room'
                then title
           end) as "6th Grade - Referring teacher's room",
       . . .
from t
group by id;
```